# In MongoDb how to get the max\min\avg\count of a single matched element occurred inside an embedded array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a `MongoDB` collection as below. And I want to get the `min\max\avg\count` of the `xxx` field inside all documents which `$match: { "Parsed.FileId": "421462559", "Parsed.MessageId": "123" }`

Note that `Fields` of each document only contains one single field with `SchemaName = xxx`

Is it possible with `MongoDB aggregation` (or other feature) and how?

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(409),
    "Parsed" : {
            "FileId" : "421462559",
            "MessageId": "123",
            "Fields" : [
                    {
                            "SchemaName" : "xxx",
                            "Type" : 0,
                            "Value" : 6
                    },
                    {
                            "SchemaName" : "yyy",
                            "Type" : 0,
                            "Value" : 5
                    }
            ]
    }
},
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(510),
    "Parsed" : {
            "FileId" : "421462559",
            "MessageId": "123",
            "Fields" : [
                    {
                            "SchemaName" : "xxx",
                            "Type" : 0,
                            "Value" : 10
                    },
                    {
                            "SchemaName" : "yyy",
                            "Type" : 0,
                            "Value" : 20
                    }
            ]
    }
}
```

For example collection above, I expect to get the result for field `xxx` as:

```
{
    count: 2,
    min: 6,
    max: 10,
    avg: 8
}
```

Comment: Could you post the expected json output

Comment: sure, updated the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below [**`aggregation`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yKrNDFpXah-)

Basically you need to first [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the nested array and then have to use  [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with the corresponding accumulator i.e. [**`min`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)
[**`max`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/)
[**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)
[**`$avg`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "Parsed.Fields.SchemaName": "xxx" }},
  { "$unwind": "$Parsed.Fields" },
  { "$match": { "Parsed.Fields.SchemaName": "xxx" }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    "max": { "$max": "$Parsed.Fields.Value" },
    "min": { "$min": "$Parsed.Fields.Value" },
    "avg": { "$avg": "$Parsed.Fields.Value" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! I missed the $unwind operator!